# Azure Ad integration in Azure functions with swagger

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, swagger

I am using Azure functions V3 with swagger UI. I am using the below code in my start up

```
builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(),opts => {
                opts.SpecVersion = Microsoft.OpenApi.OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
                opts.Title = "Platform Data Operations";
      


            });
```

I have configured the Azure Ad authentication for my app in the azure portal.
Set up the permissions and redirect Uri.I am able to login successfully from the browser after calling the redirect URI.
Can some one help me with how to integrate in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the sample code below,

```
 builder.AddSwashBuckle(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), opts =>
        {
            opts.SpecVersion = OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
            opts.ConfigureSwaggerGen = (x =>
            {
                x.DocumentFilter<CustomSwaggerDocumentAttribute>();
                x.EnableAnnotations();
                x.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc =>
                {
                    return apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)
                        ? methodInfo.Name
                        : new Guid().ToString();
                });
            });
            // remove code as query parameter
            opts.AddCodeParameter = false;
            opts.PrependOperationWithRoutePrefix = true;
            opts.Title = "Sample Function API Swagger";
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @sajeetharan but the above code does not use the Oauth libraries related to Azure AD

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: i want to integrate Azure Ad in my start up

Comment: That does not have any relationship with swagger, https://cmatskas.com/create-an-azure-ad-protected-api-using-azure-functions-and-net-core-3-1/

Comment: this should help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-dotnet-webapi-azurefunctions/ms-identity-dotnet-webapi-azurefunctions/